# How to specify bootloader for qemu-system-arm emulator

Tags: assembly, qemu, bootloader, gnu-assembler

I have very simple bootloader written in ARMv7 syntax. It is just infinite loop with some padding to make it bootable:

```
.global _start
_start:
B .

.space 510-(.-_start)
.byte 0x55, 0xaa
```

I assemble this to object file with:

```
arm-linux-gnu-as -mcpu=cortex-a15 -o dist/output.o bootsect.s
```

Then, I make binary file with:

```
arm-linux-gnu-objcopy -O binary -o dist/output.bin dist/output.o
```

This gives me perfectly fine bootable binary file.

The problem is, when I try to run it in `qemu-system-arm` with this command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M virt -cpu cortex-a15 dist/output.bin
```

it just runs Qemu monitor with some CLI. But I want to run my bootloader not some qemu specific file.

Where do I make mistake? It was working perfectly fine when I was writing in x86 syntax, compile with `nasm -f bin ...` and run with `qemu-system-i385 dist/output.bin`.
I think I'm not running qemu with correct options and it runs its own bootloader or some program.

Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: link it first  arm...ld -Ttext=0 dist/output.o -o dist/output.elf  then objcopy dist/output.elf -O binary dist/output.bin

Comment: but I dont think qemu needs a binary image file like that I think it is quite happy with an elf binary (not an elf object though).

Comment: nasm can make executables afaik  but gas does not you need to link

Comment: Thanks for answer. I linked it too. But still, qemu-system-arm -M virt -cpu cortex-a15 dist/output.bin command do not start my bootloader :/

Comment: I think (based on "Hardware configuration information for bare-metal programming" at https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/arm/virt.html ) you want to create a flash image file that contains your ROM/boot loader, possibly with the "`-pflash=dist/output.bin`" command line option. The alternative is to pretend you are Linux and let Qemu do the boot loader's job for you.

Comment: qemu can/will just load whatever as ram.  question is how do you know that it did or did not start your bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

strap.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
ldr r0,=0x101f1000
mov r1,#0x30
top:
    str r1,[r0]
    add r1,r1,#1
    and r1,r1,#0x37
    b top
```

build

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -march=armv5t strap.s -o strap.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld strap.o -Ttext=0 -o strap.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D strap.elf > strap.list
```

run

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel strap.elf
```

It will spew

```
0123456701234567012345670123456701234567012345670123456701234...
```

Until you ctrl-a then x to exit.

The qemu folks tend to not completely emulate a uart in that they do not fake the time it takes to send the character, and filling of the buffers, etc.  So you can spam the tx register and for the ones I have tried so far it works.

In any case I did not do the research on your behalf to find the address for the machine you want to run to find the address for the uart tx register.

Now if I leave out -kernel then I get

> WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'strap.bin' and probing
> guessed raw. Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw
> images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted. Specify the
> 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.

and I only spent so much time trying to find an alternate that would take an elf or -O binary type binary.  And so perhaps there is a case that does want a raw binary image and not support elf.

The x86 sim and the arm sim may be fundamentally different even with the name  qemu up front, so there may be different defaults, or may have been some luck involved in one or the other.

Note

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu cortex-a15 -m 128M -nographic -kernel strap.elf
```

also worked for me with the code shown above.